# How to configure unit test name/description on VSTS?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, azure-devops, nunit

I have a solution that contains a unit test project. I'm using NUnit v3.10.1 and NUnit3TestAdapter v3.10.0.

Is there a way to configure how the test names are displayed in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS), maybe displaying the test class name? At the moment it displays only the test name:

[image: Test names in VSTS]

It's hard to understand which test belongs to which class. In this case, I have at least 2 test classes that have the same test names.

Running the same tests using Reshaper's test runner it's quite easy to understand which tests belong to which classes:

[image: Resharper unit tests grouped by project structure]

I have tried settings the `TestName` of the [TestFixture Attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixture-Attribute) attribute or setting the `Description` of the [Test Attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Attribute) with no luck:

```
[TestFixture(TestName = "MemoryCacheManagerTests_TryGetItem", TestOf = typeof(MemoryCacheManager))]
public class MemoryCacheManagerTests_TryGetItem : MemoryCacheManagerTests
{
    [Test(Description = "MemoryCacheManagerTests_TryGetItem_WithInvalidCacheKey_ShouldThrowArgumentException")]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(InvalidCacheKeyTestCases))]
    public void WithInvalidCacheKey_ShouldThrowArgumentException(string key)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So how do I configure the names of the tests on VSTS?

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no way to configure it. You can submit a UserVoice item to suggest product improvements.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Hard to believe that configuring the names of the tests OR grouping them by class name or project structure is not possible yet on VSTS! 

Someone else asked for this kind of functionality  2 years ago, but there aren't that many votes for this feature: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/15801964-vsts-group-test-results-by-namespace-class

Comment: Updated feedback link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vstest-run-log-should-output-test-class-name-in-ad/411129