# Azure DevOps display Test Classes of Assembly in VsTest results

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to display the UnitTest Classes of a TestAssemlby inside the VsTest Result tab?

[image]

Currently we only have informations about the TestAssembly.dll and the unit test method, but not the ut test class. Is there a way to read out that information and display it inside the VsTest tab?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: [How to configure unit test name/description on VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879444/how-to-configure-unit-test-name-description-on-vsts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue , at present,  I am afraid we cannot display the class name in the Test tab. VsTest task uses the DLL for VS test and generated the .trx file which is read for our reporting parser. To solve it unless we can change our parser to also append classname in title as well.

If there are many tests with the same name in different test classes, without the test class name is easy to confuse. So, I also think this is a good feature that the product group can consider with. In addition, until now, in our official feature suggestion for Azure Devops forum, there has been a such suggestion exist in it: [VsTest run log should output test class name in addition to test name](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/411129/vstest-run-log-should-output-test-class-name-in-ad.html). You can comment and vote it there. Thanks for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.